# Highcharts JQuery - Changing the Colour of each Dot Point

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I have a line graph that is displaying variable information (% figure each month for the last 12 months)

I would like to change the dot colour of each plot based on the result that I recieved from a Ajax call to php function. (refer to the green line)

for example below is my graph: 
[My Graph](http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/4336/examplels.jpg)

if the figure for the month is > 98.5 make the dot green, If the figure is between 96 - 98.5 make the dot amber and anything lower make the dot red.

Is this possible?

i tried returning an array of colours back to my ajax method and tried:
name: 'Production Success Rate',
      color: 'responseJSON.colour,
      type: 'line',
     data: responseJSON.percent

the array responseJSON.colour that is returned is an array of hex codes.

however it seems that the color api does not allow an array as it only colours the line with the first colour in the array (unfortunatly)

can anyone help?

Comment: Are you using "High Charts" library?

Comment: Make a JSFiddle and post the link..

Comment: yes I am using the highcharts library...I will try a JSFiddle EDIT sorry not sure how to create a JSfiddle with my code as most of the back end is using PHP

Comment: `Please send email to anditburns@gmail.com if you would like to see it.` No, upload it somewhere so that it is part of the question.

Comment: Why don't you check each point value and if necessary change it's color ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you want is to leverage the `fillColor` of each series point.

This can be done by manually building the data that's to be prepared for the chart, a quick example would be:

```
var figures = [93, 95.8, 99.2, 97.8, 98.3, 96.4, 95, 98.9, 97.2, 94.3, 97.1, 94],
        d = [];

$.each(figures, function (i, figure) {
    if (figure > 98.5) {
        d.push({y: figure, fillColor: 'green', color: 'green'});
    }else if(figure < 98.5 && figure > 96.5){
        d.push({y: figure, fillColor: '#ffbf00', color: '#ffbf00'});  //amber i guess
    }else if(figure < 96.5){
        d.push({y: figure, fillColor: 'red', color: 'red'});   
    }
});
```

Then when you build the chart, simply supply `data: d` and each of the dots will have a different fill color based on the above conditional..

[I think this jsFiddle probably covers most of what you need.](http://jsfiddle.net/6szVS/)

Comment: Thank you Ohgodwhy!! that is fantastic got it working..how would I then go about changing the label itself to the same colour as the dot? at the moment if you hover on the dot the dot and label change back to the line colour?

Comment: @user2003089 That's a great question, I've never had to change the label color on hover. I'll take a look into it and get back to you shortly.

Comment: @ ohgodwhy I worked on it a little bit last night but couldnt figure it out :( let me know if you get a solution and ill let you know if I happen to get a solution as well

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>

$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            marker: {
                states: {
                    select: {
                        fillColor: 'red',
                        lineWidth: 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
});
});
```

see above as an example of how to change the selected marker colour as demonstrated in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-states-select-fillcolor/). you can customise the colours by following [these](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series.data) instructions. Good luck!

Hope this helps, Rachel :)