# Highcharts tips ? How can I add a class or an id to an Hichcharts DOM component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I want to :

- Display a tooltip when an xAxis title is hovered.
- Trigger functions when a legend element is selected/unselected.
- Trigger functions when a click is triggered on a rect html element.
- Display just one dataLabel per column.

For my two first goals, I haven't found what I was searching for in the Highcharts API reference.
Actually I'm using the Jquery selector `$("#graph span:eq(0)")`  (with Highcharts option useHTML enabled)  for selecting all the legend elements that I need, and the selector `$("#graph tspan:eq(0)")` for xAxis titles.
I would like to know if there is a native Highcharts solution for doing what I want to do. If not, Whether there is or not a solution, how can I add an id or a class to an Highcharts DOM component ? It would help me in many other cases.

For the third goal, I've been using the Highchart click event. But all the different parts of my columns are considered independently. That's why I was thinking of using the same sort of tricks than above.

For the last one, I want to display the total of a column, but just once.

There is an example of charts with witch I use to work : https://jsfiddle.net/BluePampa/L2b04cfk/

I can do what I want with those Jquery tricks, but I want to know if there is some proper way to do it. I'm also interested in any informations/tips who could help me.

Comment: have a look at this i just made it 5 mins ago for another question http://jsfiddle.net/LdHYt/390/

Comment: Thanks Rachel ! But on your example, what I see is a one-off tooltip and not a datalabel, which is different in highcharts

Comment: i can find an example of that for you. i still think i deserve an upvote.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3h7x9jst/3/ have a look at this

Comment: I was searching the "answers tab" :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721593/convert-bar-bullet-chart-into-column-chart/31723696#31723696 i answered this

Comment: here's how to change the color of each dot point of your graph. (upvote would be nice ) http://stackoverflow.com/a/14620893/1675954

Comment: totals displayed at bottom http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-parsed/

Comment: Relax, I've voted up both of them. Thanks for your implication Rachel, but once again that's not really what I wanted, I want to display on the inside of my highcharts component.
I'm going to do it with jquery selectors, and if you want I will make you know the result :)

Answer (score 1):

**Display a tooltip when an xAxis title is hovered.**

You can use the custom-events extension which allows to catch events on xAxis labels. Then find a current point "with the same x", looping over series / points. Next step is refresh tooltip.

Simple demo how to show tooltip

```
chart.tooltip.refresh(chart.series[1].points[2]);
```

**Trigger functions when a legend element is selected/unselected.**

You can catch [legendItemClick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick).

```
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function () {
                    alert('action');
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

**Trigger functions when a click is triggered on a rect html element.**

I guess that you mean column, if yes you can catch [point.events.click](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.click).

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                        alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

**Display just one dataLabel per column.**

I guess that you mean [stackLabels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.stackLabels), correct?

Comment: >Display just one dataLabel
Sorry, I wasn't precise enough, I was actually trying to do that for stacked column. Defaulty, I have one datalabels printed per column portion.
The tooltip.shared option allowed me to display just one tooltip per stacked column. How can I do that for datalabels ?

Comment: > Trigger functions when a legend element is selected/unselected
So, for stacked columns I should call the same function for each portion of a stacked column ? Is there a more general way to do that ?

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: >Trigger functions when a legend element is selected/unselected 
Is there a way to trigger the event of displaying or not a chart portions (when we click on a legend element), without enabling legend ?

Comment: > Trigger functions when a legend - so series should disappear but not be "shaded" in legend, correct?

Comment: Nop, I would rather totally suppress the legend, while keeping the possibility to use all events which came with.

Comment: Honestly this is still unclear for me, could you explain what you need step by step? What should happen?

Comment: You gave me the response on an other post :)
I was searching for a way to access to this show event without using a trigger click on legends elements.