# How to use plotOptions in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The problem I have is that all the json we pass over come from python, and we can't send over javascript in such things. For instance', I need to include [the tech from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944699/can-i-use-two-different-formatters-for-highchart-tooltips) but obviously in the plotOptions. I'm just not sure how to do things like reference series, etc. So an example with the above series would be great. I tried the following but it didn't work since `this` is not what I expected it to be.

```
     options.plotOptions = options.plotOptions || {};
    options.plotOptions.series = options.plotOptions.series || {};
    options.plotOptions.series.point =
        options.plotOptions.series.point || {};
    options.plotOptions.series.point.events =
        options.plotOptions.series.point.events || {};
    options.plotOptions.tooltip = {formatter: function() {
    var text = '';
    if(this.series.name == 'MSFT') {
        text = this.x + ': ' + this.series.name +
               '<br> $' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
    } else {
        text = 'In ' + this.x + ' the median value was' + this.median +
               'and the total $' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
    }
    return text;
    }
    options.plotOptions.series.point.events.click = function() {
        if (this.options.url){
           window.open(this.options.url);
        }
    }
```

Comment: have a look at these fiddles (i made two of them) http://jsfiddle.net/3h7x9jst/3/  ,   http://jsfiddle.net/LdHYt/390/,   http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-states-select-fillcolor/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721593/convert-bar-bullet-chart-into-column-chart/31723696#31723696

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620249/highcharts-jquery-changing-the-colour-of-each-dot-point/14620893#14620893

Comment: you can vote them up if you feel like it!!

Comment: Any time *this* isn't what you expect, or you're not sure what *this* is, just *console.log(this)* and see what it gives you. With highcharts, you can often find a path from where you are to what you need...